# What is the word that means to make a given paragraph into bullet points?

Tags: verbs, phrase-requests

I think I'm looking for a verb here.

It's something similar in sense to when one would say 'I'll annotate it'; they're taking a given text and adding meaning to it. I'm trying to say I will convert it to a specific style.

Comment: The word I would use here is **summarize**

Comment: "I'm trying to say I will convert it to a specific style."  In this case, that is exactly what you *should* say:  "I will convert it to a bullet-list style."  Not everything has a word for it.

Comment: _Bulletpointationize_ falutes very highly.

Comment: @JohnLawler funny you mention that... although not technically English, my old boss used to ask me to "bullet-point" emails or the like.

Comment: That actually is likely. Zero-derivation ("verbing" in this case) is the most common way to change part of speech in English. It's so common a method that everybody has encountered lots of strange zero-derived verbs and developed a strategy for interpreting them. In this case, as often happens, it gets a causative meaning.

Comment: There is no word for "making a paragraph into bullet points". You can substitute bullet points for a paragraph.  You can write bullet points based on a paragraph. You create bullet points from a paragraph. The word is not summarize. And like most questions of the type: what is the word for x, there isn't one. Just write the idea is my advice.

Comment: @Lambie you can "summarize a paragraph into bullet points", and if this request is frequent, you can omit all but "summarize".

Comment: @Othya You can do anything you like. But would an editor (English language editor) "like it"? I would not say summarize x into. Summarize a book, summarize a paper. Summarize ideas. No summarizing into for me.

Answer (score 1):

Verbs *itemize* and *list* each work here.

You are creating a list of things that were covered in the paragraph.

---

> Verb: itemize  'I-tu,mIz
>
> Specify individually
>
> "She itemized the many obstacles she had encountered";
>
> - enumerate, recite, itemise [Brit]
>
> Place on a list of items
>
> "itemize one's tax deductions";
>
> - itemise [Brit]

-- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=itemize)

---

> Verb: list  list
>
> Give or make a list of; name individually; give the names of
>
> "List the states west of the Mississippi";
>
> - name
>
> Include in a list
>
> "Am I listed in your register?"
>
> Enumerate
>
> "We must list the names of the great mathematicians";
>
> - number

-- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=list)

Answer (score -2):

How about **udumbrate**?

> **adumbrate** *verb*
>
> to produce a faint image or resemblance of; to outline or sketch

*Source: Dictionary.com*

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think this word is appropriate here. OP is asking a fairly specific question.

Comment: It's not right, but it's my "word of the day", so thanks.

Comment: @Othya I appreciate that; thank you. But I don't see how it doesn't fit. I know it's not perfect, but I don't think it's completely off-track.